# JSOUP: -1 error loading URL

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I want to parse one paragraph from a website. I want to parse the first paragraph in *post* div:

[image]

**I am using AsyncTask to retrieve the data. This is the doInBackground function:**

```
@Override
protected Elements doInBackground(String... url) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url[0]).timeout(10*1000).get();
        return doc.select("div.post > p");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new Elements();
}
```

**However I always get this in Logcat:**

> java.io.IOException: -1 error loading URL
>   http://www.vaccinestoday.eu/diseases/disease/rabies/
>
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:414)
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:391)
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:157) 05-17
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:146) 05-17
>   at com.c0dehunter.aZDR.diseaseActivity$getDataTask.doInBackground(diseaseActivity.java:46)
>   at com.c0dehunter.aZDR.diseaseActivity$getDataTask.doInBackground(diseaseActivity.java:1)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) 05-17 10:22:32.937:
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 05-17
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

If you click on link you'll see you can open it normally. What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you try this on a real device as well ? I keep getting the same error on emulator but on device, it smoothly works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your connect and it ran just fine. I can't say the same about your query. It doesn't bring you exactly what you want.. So i kind of enhanced it:

```
doc.select("div[class=post-entry] > p");
doc.select("div.post-entry > p");
```

Any of those will basically get ALL of the post. From now on, you can keep going solo, can't you? Anything else you need, just ask.